# Open Redirection security issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, fortify

Here i written the below code

```
 var id = Request.QueryString["id"].Trim();

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
 {
  Response.Redirect("display.aspx?id=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(id), true);
 }
 else if (CheckCredentials())
 {
  Response.Redirect("display.aspx", true);
 }
```

In the above code id is "string".  Fortify tool is showing the Open redirect issue in the above highlighted line. Anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I understood it right, but this might help you:
if you know that id is a string, why not declare it as so:
    `string id = Request.QueryString["id"].Trim();`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any "highlighted line" so which line are you refering to?

Also, why are you html encoding a string that is going to end up in a URL?
URL Encoding and HTML Encoding are two completely different things and incompatible in many ways.

The id value just came out of the URL so you can simply use it in the redirect without any issues.

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"].Trim();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
    Response.Redirect("display.aspx?id=" + id, true);
}
else if (CheckCredentials())
{
    Response.Redirect("display.aspx", true);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you @AlexCode for your response , I tried the above way also but fortify is still showing the error.

Comment: Hi mate. It's being flagged as an Open Redirect security flaw but as you're not passing an url as parameter, I don't understand what Fortify is expecting, and I can't find any useful documentation on their side.
They base themselves on the OWASP specs so here's a couple of useful links to understand the problem but still I can't figure out what Fortify is expecting as a solution.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet
https://www.troyhunt.com/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-10/